# Collection.AsQueryable() returns NullReferenceException when mapping with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper, nullreferenceexception

I am still a bit new to programming. I have the following method in my LessonsService:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetUserLessonsTableDataAsync<T>(string userId, string sortColumn, string sortColumnDirection, string searchValue)
{
    var user = await this.usersRepository
        .AllAsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Trainer)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.Lessons)
        .Include(x => x.Member)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.Lessons)
        .ThenInclude(lm => lm.Lesson)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);

    IQueryable<Lesson> lessons;

    if (user.Trainer != null)
    {
        lessons = user.Trainer.Lessons.AsQueryable();
    }
    else
    {
        var lessonsMembers = user.Member.Lessons.Where(x => x.MemberId == user.MemberId);
        var lessonsList = new List<Lesson>();

        foreach (var lessonMember in lessonsMembers)
        {
            lessonsList.Add(lessonMember.Lesson);
        }

        lessons = lessonsList.AsQueryable();
    }

    var lessonData = from lesson in lessons select lesson;

    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection)))
    {
        lessonData = lessonData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
    {
        lessonData = lessonData.Where(l => l.Topic.Contains(searchValue)
                            || l.StartingTime.Equals(searchValue)
                            || l.Group.Name.Contains(searchValue)
                            || l.Trainer.User.FirstName.Contains(searchValue)
                            || l.Trainer.User.LastName.Contains(searchValue));
    }

    return lessonData.To<T>().ToList();
}
```

For some reason this code throws System.NullReferenceException with message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I debugged and noticed that lessonData is not null, it is full with data from the database. Apparently, the mapping method **.To< T >()** is not working properly as it returns the following:

[image: Results view screenshot]

My controller is:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserLessons()
{
    try
    {
        var userId = this.HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId");
        var draw = this.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
        var start = this.Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
        var length = this.Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
        var sortColumn = this.Request.Form["columns[" + this.Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
        var sortColumnDirection = this.Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
        var searchValue = this.Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
        int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
        int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
        int recordsTotal = 0;

        var lessonData = await this.lessonsService.GetUserLessonsTableDataAsync<LessonViewModel>(userId, sortColumn, sortColumnDirection, searchValue);

        recordsTotal = lessonData.Count();

        var data = lessonData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        var jsonData = new { draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal, data };

        return this.Ok(jsonData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The exception message in the stack trace is the following:

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIPartitionIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ChessBurgas64.Services.Data.LessonsService.<GetUserLessonsTableDataAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext() in F:\ChessclubBurgas64WebApp\ChessBurgas64\Services\ChessBurgas64.Services.Data\LessonsService.cs:line 211
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ChessBurgas64.Web.Controllers.UsersController.<GetUserLessons>d__17.MoveNext() in F:\ChessclubBurgas64WebApp\ChessBurgas64\Web\ChessBurgas64.Web\Controllers\UsersController.cs:line 171
```

I have a static class (where the method .To< T >() is positioned) that is referenced in the lessonsService:

```cs
public static class QueryableMappingExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TDestination> To<TDestination>(
        this IQueryable source,
        params Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        return source.ProjectTo(AutoMapperConfig.MapperInstance.ConfigurationProvider, null, membersToExpand);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TDestination> To<TDestination>(
        this IQueryable source,
        object parameters)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        return source.ProjectTo<TDestination>(AutoMapperConfig.MapperInstance.ConfigurationProvider, parameters);
    }
}
```

Inoticed that this happens only to navigational properties (in this case it's **user.Trainer.Lessons**). If I get the lessons directly from the repository with
**lessons = this.lessonsRepository.All().Where(...);**, there will be no problem and everything will work fine, because the collection will be then a **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable** instead of **System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Lesson]**. So I guess the problem is that the method **.AsQueryable()** is not really converting the lessons to **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable**, which is needed for the mapping method **.To< T >()** to work properly? What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Where is AutoMapper called? Post the actual full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` as text in the question itself. You should seriously consider whether using the "repository" *anti*pattern offers anything here or makes it impossible to understand what this code does. After all, you have a *lot* of EF-specific calls like `Include` and `AllAsNoTracking`, so you aren't abstracting anything

Comment: Your code has no calls to EF Core. t's unclear where the error is raised too. It's quite possible that the error is correct - the loaded objects have some empty navigation properties, so when Automapper tries to use the properties of those missing entities, it throws

Comment: Thank you for your response. Forgive me, I am a bit new to programming so my post is a bit chaotic. I edited and added some more code to it. I see you refer to the repository pattern as an "antipattern" which intrigues me as I see different opinions on this topic. Can you provide more information about why is it bad to use repository pattern? Thank you.

Comment: You are looking for Query() not AsQueryable(), it won't do you any good here. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit#querying-related-entities on how to compose a query on a collection/reference already in the entity tracker.